# How many objects are eligible for Garbage Collection? JAVA

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am working through a practice Java Certification exam, and the correct answer was accidentally not provided.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test s1 = new Test();
    Test s2 = new Test();
    Test s3 = new Test();
    s1 = s3;
    s3 = s2;
    s1 = s2;
   }
}
```

Which statement is true? (Line 11 is the line s1 = s2)

A. After line 11, three objects are eligible for garbage collection.

B. After line 11, two objects are eligible for garbage collection.

C. After line 11, one object is eligible for garbage collection.

D. After line 11, none of the objects are eligible for garbage collection.

My initial thought is B.
This is because the objects s1, s2, s3 are all now pointing to the same object in memory, and thus the other 2 references would no longer be needed, but I am very uncertain of this.

Comment: apologies, I updated the post to highlight which line is "11"

Comment: `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are not objects, they are local variables.

Comment: After line `s1 = s2` **all** objects are eligible for garbage collection, because the methods ends at that point, which means all three objects are eligible.

Comment: @user16320675 Even if we assume that the method doesn't end immediately after that line, IIRC (but I'm too lazy to double check right now), nothing in the JVM spec or the JLS prevents early eligibility for GC of local variables if they are no longer used. Though I believe in practice this will only happen if the compiler reuses the slot of a local variable for a different local variable.

Comment: @user16320675 And as to `args`: the array referenced by `args` may still be referenced by the code calling `main`, which means it may not yet be eligible for GC when the `main` method ends. In other words, the presence of the parameter `args` does not in any way invalidate answer A or answer B (answer C and D are already invalidated by the code itself).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right in that local variables do not prevent garbage collection of the referenced objects. In fact, there is very little that guarantees that an object won’t be collected. Even actively using an object does not, as an optimizer could transform the code in a way that it doesn’t need the object’s memory. Regarding `args`, we do indeed not know whether the caller prevents its collection, but if not, we do not know how many (collectible) strings it contains. Or how many other now-unreachable objects the caller created before entering the main method.

Comment: @ProteinShakes your initial thought is correct in the sense that this is most likely the answer the author of this exam will consider “correct”, but as the discussion in the comments should have pointed out, the question itself is bad and has no real answer, as depending on the point of view, a lot of answers could be correct and having exactly two objects garbage collected at this point is the least likely outcome in real life. In most cases, the JVM will terminate after “line 11”, freeing the entire heap memory, but without running the garbage collector at all.

Answer (score -1):

Lets call s1="A", s2="B", s3="C"

```
s1 = s3;
s3 = s2;
s1 = s2;
```

After these lines we have the following attributes:
s1="B", s2="B", s3="C"
If you assume that you want to remove duplicates, you are going to remove one object, so the answer should be C

Comment: All three are eligible, because the method ends after line `s1 = s2`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).